# How to execute test scripts at the same time different IE tabs which have opened the same URL

Tags: testing, watir, browser-automation

I'm executing automated test scripts in some URL in Internet Explorer.

If I open the same link on a new tab, the control gets transferred to the newly opened link that is active in the browser.

How to stop this and execute tests in the first browser instance?

Comment: Are you asking how do you stop the link from opening in a new tab? What happens when you manually click the link - does it open a new tab?

Comment: No, I am asking if I run the execution in one tab in some link,and if I manually open same link in new tab then execution get transfer to the new tab.how to stop this.Does it requires any changes in env.tb file.

Comment: It would really help if you could give an example.